# Given, $\log_{10}2=0.30103$ ,then find the number of digits in $2^{56}$

Tags: logarithms

I know basics of logarithm. I encountered this problem in my maths book.I don't know how to find number of digits in the problem. Please help me.

Comment: $2^{56} = 10^{56 \log 2}$

Comment: Can it give me number of digits in it.

Comment: Note that it is obvious from the above hint that:
$$10^{16}<10^{56\log(2)}<10^{17}$$
How many digits are in $10^{16}$, and how many digits are in $10^{17}$? Now deduce the number of digits in $10^{56\log(2)}$.

Comment: How many digits are in $10^1$? How many digits are in $10^2$? How about any exponent between $1$ and $2$? What about larger exponents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $2= 10^{\log_{10} 2}$, then $2^{56}=(10^{\log_{10} 2})^{56}=10^{56\log2}$.

Now simply substitute your given $\log2$ into the equation:

$2^{56}=10^{56 \times 0.30103}=10^{16.85768}$

Therefore it is clear your answer will be $16+1=17$ digits.

Comment: Why $\lfloor 16.85768 \rfloor + 1$? (Hint: 999 vs 1000)