# Using integers $a$ and $x$ in $a^x$, why does the # of digits of the exponentiated power multiplied by the $\log_{10}(a)$ equal $\pm1$ the exponent x?

Tags: logarithms

There have been multiple questions surrounding the determination of the number of digits in an integer power when given the base and exponent, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384917/relation-between-number-of-digits-of-a-number-and-its-logarithm/1384924#1384924) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414039/given-log-102-0-30103-then-find-the-number-of-digits-in-256).

My question isn't how to determine how many digits are in the power produced by $a^x$ or how to compute the logarithm of $\log_a(B)$ where the logarithm, base and power are integers.

My question is why given $a,B$ where $a^x=B$, does counting the digits of $B$ base $10$ and multiplying the number of digits by the result of $\log_{10}(a)$ get us to within $1$ of $x$? Is there a particular [logarithmic identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities) I'm missing?

There's some relationship I'm not connecting between $2^{56}$ = $10^{16.857679757182943}$ where the $\lfloor 16.857679757182943\rfloor+1$ is equal to the number of digits of both exponentiated powers $72057594037927936$ from $2^{56}$ and $10^{16.857679757182943}$.

**Caveat:** If based upon my naiveté in math, the preceding questions I referenced, should have given me my answer and therefore this question is duplicative I will remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you have $$16 < \log_{10}{2^{56}} < 17,$$ which means that $$10^{16}<2^{56}<10^{17}.\tag{1}$$  Now, $10^{16}$ has $17$ digits, and $10^{17}$ is the smallest integer with $18$ digits, so $2^{56}$ has $17$ digits.

Taking base-two logarithms in $(1)$ gives
$$16\log_2{10}<56<17\log_2{10}$$

Comment: Forgive if what you've provided is obvious, but I'm not seeing the connection between  $2^x$ having 17 digits and being able to determine the value for $x$ by computing $17⋅log_{2}(10)$?

Comment: Does my edit help?